# Glide suddenly stopped loading drawable stored in my resources folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I was loading drawables from res folder using Glide. Images were loading properly until yesterday, but today after installing fresh build glide is not loading images now. I have not made any code changes and on debugging also I am not getting and crash or exception. I am shown blank screen now. Not able to understand why this happened suddenly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, we need more information. I suggest that you create a new project in Android Studio and build up the minimal amount of code that is needed to reproduce your problem. It is highly likely that doing this will help you sole the problem yourself. If you don't, then you have a much clearer idea of what the problem is and can explain it to us much better. Also, when you share the code, it will help us better understand what you are trying to do and we will have better chances of actually helping you from there.

Comment: I did created sample and copied my exact code in it. But in sample it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my app package name and after doing it I moved my files inside separate packages and Glide started working fine. Could not understand what was issue earlier.